# Updating AWS API Gateway's lamda authorizer is still referring to old authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I created an authorizer for an API and deployed it in AWS. Later I created another authorizer and attached the API gateway with the new authorizer. But when invoking the API, it still uses the old authorizer. What should I do to invalidate the older one?

*Note: I need the old one as well for a different API call, so there are two authorizers in it.*

> GET - /api/users uses Admin Authorizer
> PUT - /api/users/{username} uses User Authorizer

Comment: Did you `deploy` the Api Gateway again? By e.g. pressing the "Deploy" button in the ui and selecting the stage you want to deploy to, etc.!?

Comment: I was using the serverless framework to deploy, seems like it didn't make the deploying done. After I manually deployed it seems to be working. thanks.